# Parse migration final process

Tags: parse-platform, migration, database-migration, parse-server

I migrated my app to AWS. I setup my app and its working perfectly in my new server.

Parse sent me an email about migration process.

Hello Parse developer,

Your database migration is almost complete.

You may now switch to your new database by going to your app and finalizing the migration. You have less than 24 hours to make this change, otherwise your job will be cancelled.

If you need additional assistance, please visit https://parse.com/help, open a ticket, and include the JobID of your migration.

Thank you,
Parse Team

Replies to this email are not monitored.

So what should I do now to finalize my migrate ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Parse.com dashboard there is a page called Migration, and in this page you can finalize the migration process.

Comment: So that's it. Now you suppose to migrate your server